# "this" and "next" in mongoose middleware with TS not working

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I am trying to make middleware work with Typescript, but both this and next in `pre` and `post` are not working correctly, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
schema.pre("updateOne", function (this: IDepartment, next: HookNextFunction) {
  console.log("pre update department"); // <- logs: pre update department
  console.log(this.peopleCount);        // <- logs: undefined
  next();                               // throws error: next is not a function
});
```

`IDepartment` is the interface that I have created for the Department document.

The middleware does get called, as both consoles log, but `this.peopleCount` logs undefined, and when it gets to `next()` it throws error that `next is not a function`.

This is my interface:

```
import { Document } from "mongoose";

interface IEmployeeInput {
  departmentId: string;
  employeeSkills: {
    primaryIDs: string;
    secondaryIDs: string[];
  };
  egn: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  middleName: string;
}

export interface IEmployee extends IEmployeeInput, Document {
  internalCompanyId: string;
  fullName: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
  schedule: number;
}
```

And the Schema:

```
import { model, models, Schema, HookNextFunction } from "mongoose";

import { IDepartment } from "~/types";

const schema = new Schema<Required<IDepartment>>({
  initials: { length: 4, type: String },
  name: { maxlength: 20, minlength: 4, required: true, type: String, unique: true },
  peopleCount: { type: Number, required: true },
});

schema.pre("updateOne", function (this: IDepartment, next: HookNextFunction) {
  console.log("pre update department");
  console.log(this.peopleCount);
  next();
});

export const DepartmentModel = models.Department || model<IDepartment>("Department", schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a [certain quirk](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware) in handling updateOne and deleteOne middlewares assigned by `schema.pre` calls:

> Unlike `schema.pre('remove')`, Mongoose registers `updateOne` and
> `deleteOne` middleware on `Query#updateOne()` and `Query#deleteOne()` by
> default. This means that both `doc.updateOne()` and `Model.updateOne()`
> trigger `updateOne` hooks, but `this` refers to a query, not a document.

You'll need to modify the middleware-registering code to force its assignment to Document:

```
schema.pre('updateOne', 
  { document: true, query: false }, 
  function() { ... });
```